# In serverless（aws）， how to get variable reference from serverless.yml file?

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless

In Serverless.yml, I defined resource:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs6.10
  region: us-east-1
  stage: dev
  environment:
    customerDef: myvariable
resources:
  Resources:
    NewResource:
     Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
     Properties:
      BucketName: ${self:service.name}-${self:provider.stage}-uploads
```

while in handler.js file which is write handle function.

How to get the reference of BucketName?

How to get the Bucket URI?

How to get the customerDef variable value? (provider->environment->customerDef)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the environment variables defined under the `environment` node are available at any `.js` file using `process.env.<variable_name>`.

In your case, to access the `customerDef` variable you should use `process.env.customerDef`.

You can do the same with the BucketName and Bucket URI.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your variables in environment key, you can reference them by process.env.yourVariable in every part of your project

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).